# Running Snakemake rules in containers without Singularity

Tags: docker, snakemake

I would like to implement the following pipeline in Snakemake, to run on my Mac OS X M1 laptop for compiling LaTeX documents.

[image]
Source: [How to annoy your co-authors: a Gitlab CI pipeline for LaTeX](https://blog.martisak.se/2020/05/11/gitlab-ci-latex-pipeline/)

I am running Rancher locally, which means I can Docker images in `containerd` using `nerdctl`, or in Kubernetes. To run Singularity I seem to need to use a virtual machine, not sure I can on the M1. Furthermore, I have installed Snakemake using `pipenv`.

Specifically, I want to run the following for this rule.

```
nerdctl run --rm -v $(pwd):/data -w /data martisak/texlive:2022 -- sh -c 'xelatex testme.tex'
```

My first attempt involved running a very long shell command in my rule which specified `nerdctl run --rm {params.dockerimage} -- sh '{params.command}'`. This quickly became a game of fixing issues with quotation, but worked! The same syntax should work also for `docker` as for `nerdctl`.

Now I am trying to use `snakemake --cluster`, but this fails because Snakemake is trying to use local paths inside the container.

Here is my full Snakefile.

### MWE

Snakefile

```
rule render:
    input:
        tex="{jobname}.tex",
    output:
        "{jobname}.pdf"
    params:
        latexcmd="xelatex",
        dockerimage="martisak/texlive:2022"
    shell:
        "{params.latexcmd} {input}"
```

testme.tex

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
First document. This is a simple example, with no 
extra parameters or packages included.
\end{document}
```

Run with

```
snakemake -c1 -j1 -p --cluster "nerdctl run --rm -v $(pwd):/data  {params.dockerimage} -- sh -c" "testme.pdf"
```

This fails since the script generated by Snakemake can't be found.

```
sh: 1: [localpath]/.snakemake/tmp.fonlxni_/snakejob.render.0.sh: not found
```

To get around this I can add `-v $(pwd):$(pwd)` to the cluster command above. Now the error becomes

```
[localpath]/document/.snakemake/tmp.dvx5_a1u/snakejob.render.0.sh: 3: [localpath]/.virtualenvs/document-_JtDMzNq/bin/python: not found
```

The file `snakejob.render.0.sh` seems to be removed after the job, but if I am really quick, I can inspect it. It will try to use `python` from the local virtual environment to `snakemake` and the same rule - but with a million flags using absolute paths.

Can't I just run the shell command, without Snakemake inside the container?
Or is there a better way of doing this? :)